# How to get data attribute from option in multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get list of selected values from multiple select?
I can get `value` only(
I need to get `attr` values `('data-name')`

https://playcode.io/301780?tabs=console&index.html&output

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="payment" style="width: 246px;" required multiple="multiple" class="select2" id="id_payment">
  <option value="3" data-name="blago">blago</option>
  <option value="4" data-name="usd" selected>usd</option>
  <option value="5" data-name="uah" selected>uah</option>
  <option value="2" data-name="btc">btc</option>
</select>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var vals = $('#id_payment').val()
    var paymentList = []

    if (vals) {
      for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        console.log(vals[i])
        paymentList.push($(vals[i]).selector)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: why not just set name as value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop thru the selected options and use `data` to get the `data-name` values.

```js
var result = $("#id_payment option:selected").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("name");
}).get();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="payment" style="width: 246px;" required multiple="multiple" class="select2" id="id_payment">
  <option value="3" data-name="blago">blago</option>
  <option value="4" data-name="usd" selected>usd</option>
  <option value="5" data-name="uah" selected>uah</option>
  <option value="2" data-name="btc">btc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` to traverse the items and collect them into an array, like:

```
var dataNames = [];
$("#id_payment > option[selected]").each(function() {
    dataNames.push($(this).data("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$("#id_payment option:selected").each(function(index, item){

         let name = $(item).data('name');
         //alert(name)
         nameselected.push(name);
         console.log(name);
   })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var vals = $('#id_payment').val()
var paymentList = []
var nameselected = []

if (vals) {
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        console.log(vals[i])
        paymentList.push($(vals[i]).selector)
    }
  }
  
   $("#id_payment option:selected").each(function(index, item){
         
         let name = $(item).data('name');
         //alert(name)
         nameselected.push(name);
         console.log(name);
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="payment" style="width: 246px;" required multiple="multiple" class="select2" id="id_payment">
        <option value="3" data-name="blago">blago</option>
        <option value="4" data-name="usd" selected>usd</option>
        <option value="5" data-name="uah" selected>uah</option>
        <option value="2" data-name="btc">btc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery `.each()` function.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="payment" style="width: 246px;" required multiple="multiple" class="select2" id="id_payment">
  <option value="3" data-name="blago">blago</option>
  <option value="4" data-name="usd" selected>usd</option>
  <option value="5" data-name="uah" selected>uah</option>
  <option value="2" data-name="btc">btc</option>
</select>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_payment :selected').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).data("name"))
    })
    $("#id_payment").click(function(){
      $('#id_payment :selected').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).data("name"))
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

It is set up so when you make more selections, it still logs all of the selected items